# What is Terry's connection to Nevada in S05E01?

Tags: plot-explanation, ray-donovan

I loved how they started the season, a lot of mysteries some got explained and others I think will be explained later. What I can't wrap my head around is what's Terry's connection to Nevada, when he said to Ray:

> it's over between me and Maureen, her brother found out about Nevada.

I can't remember anything that links him to Nevada, the only thing that is close is when Miky attempted a robbery and killed the casino manager.
Is it another mystery or there is something that I'm missing?

Comment: There is a 10-month gap between Season 4 and Season 5, and they are telling this season's stories with a fractured timeline, so my best guess is that this is something they teased so that they can pay it off and explain it somewhere down the line, further along the season.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't this simply refer to [Terry's misadventure in a whorehouse](https://www.vulture.com/2017/08/ray-donovan-recap-season-5-episode-2.html), the one we learn about in the next episode?

> But before Abby and Ray realize as much, they get to take a trip to a
>   whorehouse! **Terry claims he was framed inside — drugged, overcharged,
>   and a hooker stole his mother’s wedding ring.** They have to get it
>   back. Abby and Ray go in and pretend to want a ménage a trois for
>   their anniversary. They get Terry’s escort, pick the Dominatrix
>   package, and then get really rough. Ray pushes down on the girl’s ball
>   gag, forcing her to give up the location of the ring. Abby even gets
>   involved, threatening to use depilatory to take off all of the
>   hooker’s hair, before she tells them the ring is in the Midol. It’s a
>   decent scene, but goes on a bit too long before making its point,
>   which is to give Abby doubts about Terry’s fidelity, and by extension,
>   Ray’s.

His presence there would likely cause troubles when it comes to his marriage:

> The detour also casts a pall over their anniversary trip, which is
>   intensified when Terry asks Maureen to marry him in front of Ray and
>   Abby. **Terry may claim he didn’t visit an escort for sex the night
>   before and that he was just framed, but Abby doubts his story, and she
>   doesn’t like that Terry’s marriage is starting off on that note.** It
>   also reminds her of Ray’s regular infidelity. She’s conflicted because
>   she knows something that Maureen does not, but she can’t tell her. She
>   also might be annoyed that Terry is stealing some of their
>   anniversary-dinner thunder. And she thinks she might have a fever.
>   Uh-oh.